# How to change wallpaper in Kubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, desktop-background

Can someone tell me how to change the wallpaper or background in Kubuntu 16.04?

Comment: right click on any image, set as wall paper

Comment: @SeverusTux It's a bit more complicated — drag it to the desktop, a menu will open, then select 'Image'.

Comment: Look for how to change KDE's desktop wallpaper: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1383621 Look for Desktop/Appearance/Background settings - if you can't find it, what version of KDE are you running?

Answer (score 1):

well those didnt work so i'll answer it for others. :)
yesterday in order to get folders to reside on desktop i had to unlock and enable folders, so in order to change wallpaper today i had to right click on destop and way at bottom there was "folder view settings" and there it was, wallpapers. thans.
dan